# What are all the ring homomorphisms from $A[x_1,\dots, x_n]\rightarrow A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity.

> **Is every ring homomorphism $\phi : A[x_1,\dots, x_n]\rightarrow A$ an
>   $A$ - algebra homomorphism?**

I tried to show that $\phi(a\cdot p(x_1,\dots,x_n))=a\cdot\phi(p(x_1,\dots,x_n))$ for all $a\in A$ and $p\in A[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ but all I can say is that $\phi(a\cdot p)=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(p)$. So I will be done if I can show $\phi(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$ but I don't know how to show that.

Is there an example where this is not true?

Comment: You should first ask yourself if even ring homomorphism $A \to A$ is an $A$-algebra homomorphism...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily. If there is a nontrivial ring honomorphism $\psi: A\to A$, then composing an evaluation homomorphism with $\psi$ gives you something that is not an $A$-algebra homomorphism.

For example, in the case $A=\mathbb C$, $n=1$ and $\psi$ being complex conjugation we could have
$$ \phi(a_0 + a_1X + a_2X^2 + \cdots + a_kX^k) \mapsto \overline{a_0} $$
which is not a $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism becase
$ i\cdot \phi(1) = i$ but $\phi(i\cdot 1)=-i$.